# How to validate Kendo ui components by client_side_validation on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kendo-ui, client-side-validation

I use [KendoUI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) and [client_side_validation](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) on Ruby on rails.
But some components built by KendoUI are not validated by client_side_validation. client_side_validation is unresponsive.(There is no script error.)

For example, NumericTextBox, Combobox, DropdownList, DatePicker ...
(Textbox is OK)

Why?
And, I want to know how to validate these components by client_side_validation on Ruby on rails.
Can someone help me?

My code is as follows（NumericTextBox and Combobox）

shoe.rb

```
class Shoe < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name,
        presence: true
    validates :price,
        presence: true
end
```

shoes_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @shoe = Shoe.new
    @shoe_name = Shoe.select(:name)
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(shoe, validate: true) do |f| %>
  <% if shoe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(shoe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shoe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% shoe.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:name, @shoe_name, :name, :name, {}, {:class => "my-combobox"}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price, class:"my-numeric" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

mykendo.js

```
$(".body-content .my-combobox").each(function (i, elem) {
    var e = $(elem);
    var val = e.val();
    var filter = e.attr('my-filter');
    e.kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: true,
        filter: filter,
        noDataTemplate: null,
        clearButton: false,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "text"
    });

    e.parent().attr("id", elem.id + "_parent");
    e.removeAttr("my-filter");
});

$(".body-content .my-numeric").each(function (i, elem) {
    var e = $(elem);
    var placeholder = e.attr("my-placeholder");

    e.kendoNumericTextBox({
        placeholder: placeholder === undefined ? "" : placeholder
    });

    e.removeAttr("my-numeric");
    e.removeAttr("my-placeholder");
});
```

Thank you.